# Pipe, ngModel and ngModelChange

Tags: angular, pipe, nan, ngmodel

I have a two-way data binding with a custom pipe.

My input text field code:

```HTML
<input type="text" [ngModel]="post.price | myCurrencyPipe" (ngModelChange)="post.price = $event" name="price" id ="price" (change)="itemPriceUpdate(post)"/>
```

and custom pipe code :

```ts
@Pipe({ name: 'myCurrencyPipe'})
export class MyCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform{

      transform(val:any) {
        var value = parseInt(data);
        var num = '$' + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        return num;

      }
```

When I go to edit my input field value it displays NaN on keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have character `$` at the front of `val` which added by your custom pipe. remove it before calling `parseInt(data)` will solve your problem.

```
transform(val:any) {
  val = val.toString().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  if (val === '') return '';
  var value = parseInt(val);
  var num = '$' + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  return num;
}
```

**[plinker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/53ZBBCWQVJToLjgns2Pg?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried as per your instruction. there was still NAN issue in input field. 
Now I added extra condition in custom pipe and it now displaying nan in input field. 
          if(isNaN(val)){
                 var num1='';
                 return num1;
            }

Comment: @SalmaKona parameter of `parseInt` need to be type of `number`, else it will be converted to `NAN`.

Comment: Thanks @Pengyy for your help.

Comment: @SalmaKona you can fork and reproduce your problem with the plunker I provided. and tell me by what operation will lead to `NAN`.

Comment: @SalmaKona I think I've got what you mean. :-)  when you clear the entire value will also lead to failure of `parseInt`. sorry for I didn't aware of this.

Comment: @SalmaKona seems you have to replace `,` also when your input is large than 999. :-)

Comment: @SalmaKona I have made a more sensible example which will remove all characters exclude `0-9` and `.`. hope it'll help. :-)

Comment: @ Pengyy  please share me your example.

Comment: @SalmaKona click the `plinker demo` link at my answer will lead you to there. :-)

Comment: @ Pengyy, Thanks for your help. it help me.

Comment: @SalmaKona ok, there is a `√` marker at the left side of my answer, if you click it and turn it to green color that means my answer meet your question and others who look into your question will find the answer more easily. :-)